# ListViewItem.Selected=True being overridden?

Tags: vb.net, listview

Hullo, there. First post. Please be gentle.
I am trying to move a selected item up and down a ListView control using the up and down arrows keys.
Here is my code. It is a Windows Forms project, with a form and a ListView control. MultiSelect=False. Sorting=None. View=Details. A single column.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ListView1.Items.Add("A")
    ListView1.Items.Add("B")
    ListView1.Items.Add("C")
    ListView1.Items.Add("D")
    ListView1.Items.Add("E")

End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ListView1.KeyDown

    Dim iInsertAt As Integer

    If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then

        Dim lSelectedItem As ListViewItem = ListView1.SelectedItems(0)
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Up
                If lSelectedItem.Index > 0 Then
                    iInsertAt = lSelectedItem.Index - 1
                    ListView1.Items.Remove(lSelectedItem)
                    lSelectedItem = ListView1.Items.Insert(iInsertAt, lSelectedItem)
                End If
            Case Keys.Down
                If lSelectedItem.Index < ListView1.Items.Count - 1 Then
                    iInsertAt = lSelectedItem.Index + 1
                    ListView1.Items.Remove(lSelectedItem)
                    lSelectedItem = ListView1.Items.Insert(iInsertAt, lSelectedItem)
                End If
        End Select
        lSelectedItem.Selected = True

    End If

End Sub
```

The code works fine, except that it does not correctly highlight lSelectedItem when it has been moved ^up^. If you run the code, you can select "A" and shift it down the list with the down arrow key. But the result with the up arrow key is not so good.
Would appreciate any guidance!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's happened because when you remove the item, the selected index still the same so the selection goes to the next item.

[For more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems?view=netframework-4.8)

To correct that you can do something like remove and insert two items from the list In order to maintain the order of the selected index.

**ex**:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ListView1.Items.Add("A")
    ListView1.Items.Add("B")
    ListView1.Items.Add("C")
    ListView1.Items.Add("D")
    ListView1.Items.Add("E")
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ListView1.KeyDown
    Dim iInsertAt As Integer
    If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
        Dim lSelectedItem As ListViewItem = ListView1.SelectedItems(0)
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Up
                If lSelectedItem.Index > 0 Then
                    iInsertAt = lSelectedItem.Index - 1
                    Dim item2 = ListView1.Items.Item(iInsertAt)
                    'remove and Insert two 
                    ListView1.Items.Remove(item2)
                    ListView1.Items.Insert(iInsertAt + 1, item2)
                    ListView1.Items.Remove(lSelectedItem)
                    lSelectedItem = ListView1.Items.Insert(iInsertAt, lSelectedItem)
                End If
            Case Keys.Down
                If lSelectedItem.Index < ListView1.Items.Count - 1 Then
                    iInsertAt = lSelectedItem.Index + 1
                    ListView1.Items.Remove(lSelectedItem)
                    lSelectedItem = ListView1.Items.Insert(iInsertAt, lSelectedItem)
                End If
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: First off - thanks for the code, @Mohamed. That works. But I do not understand why. Sorry to appear dense, but would appreciate your thoughts on the following.

Comment: Question 1.
I added a Textbox to the form, to trace what is selected at each stage.

Comment: `Private Sub PrintSelected(sBookmark As String)
      Text1.Text &= sBookmark & ": "
      For Each l1 As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        Text1.Text &= If(l1.Selected, "[" & l1.Text & "]", l1.Text)
      Next
      Text1.Text &= " s/i=" & If(ListView1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0, ListView1.SelectedIndices(0), "none") & vbCrLf
    End Sub`

Comment: If we take a simple case, selecting the "C" and pressing the up arrow, then my code...

Comment: `If lSelectedItem.Index > 0 Then
  PrintSelected("1")
  iInsertAt = lSelectedItem.Index - 1
  ListView1.Items.Remove(lSelectedItem)
  PrintSelected("2")
  lSelectedItem = ListView1.Items.Insert(iInsertAt, lSelectedItem)
  PrintSelected("3")
End If`

Comment: Gives the following trace...

1: AB[C]DE s/i=2
2: ABDE s/i=none
3: A[C]BDE s/i=1

Although the ListView itself actually displays - using the same notation - AC[B]DE.

Comment: Meanwhile your code...

`If lSelectedItem.Index > 0 Then
  PrintSelected("1")
  iInsertAt = lSelectedItem.Index - 1
  Dim item2 = ListView1.Items.Item(iInsertAt)
  ListView1.Items.Remove(item2)
  PrintSelected("2")
  ListView1.Items.Insert(iInsertAt + 1, item2)
  PrintSelected("3")
  ListView1.Items.Remove(lSelectedItem)
  PrintSelected("4")
  lSelectedItem = ListView1.Items.Insert(iInsertAt, lSelectedItem)
  PrintSelected("5")
End If`

Comment: Gives this trace...

1: AB[C]DE s/i=2
2: A[C]DE s/i=1
3: A[C]BDE s/i=1
4: ABDE s/i=none
5: A[C]BDE s/i=1

And the ListView does indeed show A[C]BDE.

Comment: However, from the trace it looks as though steps 4 and 5 are redundant. If I comment out everything below `PrintSelected("3")`, I do indeed get the following trace...

1: AB[C]DE s/i=2
2: A[C]DE s/i=1
3: A[C]BDE s/i=1 

But the ListView actually shows [A]CBDE. So what am I missing?

Comment: Question 2.
Quite apart from all that, why did my lSelectedItem.Selected = True not reset the selection to where I wanted it, since MultiSelect=False?